# How to make 2 divs float, left div with fixed right margin?

Tags: html, css, layout

I actually don't know how to name my question. But I will explain what I need to do.

HTML is simple as this:

```
<div id="left_div"></div>
<div id="right_div"></div>
```

I need `left_div` to be on the left, to have 100% width, but with fixed right margin 320px. `right_div` has fixed width 300px and must be alongside `left_div`.

I know I can do this very easily, when I would do this:

```
<div id="right_div" style="float:right;width:300px"></div>
<div id="left_div" style="margin-right:320px;"></div>
```

But the problem is that I need HTML to be as I mentioned before. The order of `DIVs` matter. If someone wonders why, it's because I am working on responsive website, where I need, when the viewport is too narrow, the `right_div` to be below `left_div`. And that I can't do with simple solution I have put above.

I hope my question makes sense and I am thankful for any answers or helpful hints.

Oh, and I forgot to mention I need this to be pure HTML+CSS, no JS. And I don't need to support IE7 and below.

**UPDATE:**
`left_div` must be width:auto and right margin must be fixed (e.g. 300px).

Comment: Here's the start of a jsfiddle if anyone wants to tinker w/ it:  http://jsfiddle.net/n8rbx/

Answer (score 0):

If you want your layout to be responsive you should use a CSS framework like [Columnal](http://www.columnal.com/), [1140](http://cssgrid.net/), or more in [this list](http://speckyboy.com/2011/11/17/15-responsive-css-frameworks-worth-considering/).

Most of these frameworks supports the [grid system](http://www.thegridsystem.org/), which is the best way to structure your layout and you don't have to worry about floats and pixels anymore.

Comment: Yes, that's true, frameworks are helpful, but this is very special case, where I couldn't use framework for beeing too general in some ways.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what do you want is almost impossible with just pure HTML + CSS.

What may work for you is something like this one I did: http://jsfiddle.net/fmZAm/

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="fixed_content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.main
{ 
  min-height: 500px;  /* force some height */
  min-width: 300px;   /* min width to show content */
  text-align: center; /* center content when in vertical responsive mode */
  font-size: 0px;     /* remove blank space from 'inline-block' display */
}
div.main > div  /* left and right divs */
{  
  width: 100%;           /* force both to have as max width as possible */
  min-height: inherit;   /* same min height as parent */
  min-width: inherit;    /* same min width as parent to show content */
  display: inline-block; 
}
div.left
{  
  max-width: 58%;     /* 100% width from max of 58% parent width */
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
div.right
{ 
  max-width: 42%;     /* 100% width from max of 42% parent width */
  text-align: right;  /* put child 'inline-block' divs to the right */
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
div.right > div.fixed_content
{ 
  width: 300px;        /* set the 300px right div you want */
  min-height: inherit; /* same min  height as parent */
  background: orange; 
  display: inline-block; 
}
```

As both divs (left and right) will have % widths, both will resize based on the current max width, but you'll have your fixed width div inside of the right div. So, when your right div resize to 300px width (the fixed with of its child div) it will go below the left div.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for answer, but this is not what I am looking for. I need left div to have auto width. But in your example it is fixed width. It doesn't help me a lot..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it using position:absolute.

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="left_div"></div>
  <div id="right_div"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container {
  position:relative;
}

#left_div {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 320px;
}

#right_div {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width: 300px;
}
```